# How to store Spring Boot OAuth2 logged in user in session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I'm trying to implement [Silent Authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication) for my Spring Boot Authorization Server (created via @EnableAuthorizationServer) so that I can ask for new access tokens from my SPA.

I figure that to do that, I first need to somehow convince my OAuth2 Authorization Server to store logged in users in session.

I could not find any information on how to solve my problem online.
I'm guessing that the @EnableAuthorizationServer annotation somehow disables session storage but I was unable to find where that takes place.

Let's say I "log in" to my Auth Server like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data \
  -F grant_type=password \
  -F username=demo \
  -F password=demo
```

The above will, of course, provide me with an access token. However, I would like the Auth Server to keep the user in session so that I'm able to access the controller below WITHOUT that access token:

```java
// This controller is in my Auth Server
@RestController
public class SecurityController {

    @GetMapping("silentauth")
    public String silentAuth(Principal principal) {
        return principal.toString();
    }
}
```

The idea is, once I implement the above, I will be able to provide an endpoint for "refreshing tokens", where the Authorization Server will provide a new token only if the user is currently "logged in" to that server.

Comment: have you tried Springboot 2.2.0? it has the latest Spring Security, normally you don't have anything to do since on the client side you receive a `SESSIONID` cookie

Comment: What you are talking about is the standard stateful authentication provided by Spring Boot. Unfortunately, it won't help me here.

Comment: ok, but maybe if you look into SessionRepository or the SecurityContextHolder it could help

Comment: How should the auth server determine which user is calling the `silentauth` endpoint? That info should somehow be stored in the HTTP request, because HTTP itself is logically stateless.